# How to write a framework on top of spring boot (i.e. write a spring boot application without implementing some interfaces)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, frameworks

I'd like to write a framework on top of spring boot that does a bunch of things, like exposing specific endpoints and doing specific logic.

But I'd like to build it as a `framework` in the sense that someone else can take it, implement a number of specific interfaces and it will then run as a spring boot web application.

I haven't found how to do this specifically.

I've looked into [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter) about writing a custom starter, but it looks like the dependency is the wrong way round. I want the custom code "plugged into" the framework rather than calling the classes of the starter directly, if that makes sense.

Comment: Try use Service Provider Interface

Comment: were you able to make this work ? if ur code is open source, would love to take a look and learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the `EnableAutoConfiguration` plugin. This is the core of any spring boot libraries that wants to deal with spring boot custom beans without user help.  `EnableAutoConfiguration` classes need to be placed in `spring.factories` file.

`spring.factories` file can have multiple classes each class needs to be provided using `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=A,B,C`

Using these boot classes you can create many beans that could be the backbone of your framework.  Also if you want to provide custom properties as boot does, you need to add those properties file `spring-configuration-metadata.json` file.

For your reference, you can see this repo [Rqueue](https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue/tree/master/rqueue-spring-boot-starter)

Comment: Yeah I made the autoconfiguration + starter setup work. Thanks!

Comment: @sonus21 - does your answer still stand ? i have been wondering whether to build a "framework on top of spring" using something like lombok as an alternative.

Comment: @Sandeep. yes this answer still holds till date.